# Bad authentication ClientLogin protocol Google Analytisc API?

Tags: google-api, google-analytics-api, google-authentication

I've been able to get authorization token for the past few days using:

```
curl https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin -s -d Email=eric@company.com -d Password=xxxx-d accountType=GOOGLE -d service=analytics
```

But it suddenly stopped working today and return `Error=BadAuthentication`.
I've double-checked, triple-checked my email address and password and use another account but the error has remained the same.
I've tried the same command but for `service=gmail` and I actually got a response.

What have gone wrong?
(Perhaps I've been using Google Analytics API the last few days to get pageviews statistics for my website, exceeded my quota and I'm now blocked as a result?)